# Export an aframe scene to a 360° video

Tags: three.js, aframe, webvr, 360-degrees, 360-virtual-reality

I'm trying to export a VR scene made with a-frame (three.js-based VR library) into a 360° video.

All I could find was a way to export the canvas to a regular flat mpeg4 using a chrome plugin (RenderCan). I would like it to be a video that could be watched from any angle though.

Is there a way e.g. to snapshot every frame to an equirectangular image or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can make equirectangular screenshot of aframe scene by doing

```js
document.querySelector('a-scene').components.screenshot.getCanvas('equirectangular');
```

or normal perspective screenshot of what you're looking with

```js
document.querySelector('a-scene').components.screenshot.capture('perspective');
```

Maybe you can try to make some screenshot and make a sort of gif

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this when I'm back on A-Frame